# Can't run vagrant up on laravel homestead all of a sudden

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I have been running laravel and using vagrant for a while now. I recently did a `vagrant destroy` to reload from a fresh install, and now I can't get the box to load at all. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling from scratch Virtualbox, vagrant, and homestead (I'm using composer to install it for a project-specific installation). I've made sure to enable Oracle in the Security settings on my Mac. I'm completely at a loss because the error messages are pretty useless and I've found nothing online.

**Versions of everything:**

- Mac OS Big Sur: 11.1
- Vagrant: 2.2.14
- Box version: laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 9.7.2)
- Virtual Box: 6.1.16

**Results of running `vagrant up`**

```
❯ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'tools-ui' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> tools-ui: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> tools-ui: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> tools-ui: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' version '9.7.2' is up to date...
==> tools-ui: Setting the name of the VM: tools-ui
==> tools-ui: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> tools-ui: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    tools-ui: Adapter 1: nat
    tools-ui: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> tools-ui: Forwarding ports...
    tools-ui: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    tools-ui: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    tools-ui: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    tools-ui: 4040 (guest) => 4040 (host) (adapter 1)
    tools-ui: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    tools-ui: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
    tools-ui: 9600 (guest) => 9600 (host) (adapter 1)
    tools-ui: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
    tools-ui: 9200 (guest) => 9200 (host) (adapter 1)
    tools-ui: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> tools-ui: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> tools-ui: Booting VM...
==> tools-ui: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    tools-ui: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    tools-ui: SSH username: vagrant
    tools-ui: SSH auth method: private key
    tools-ui: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'aborted' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
```

I've looked in the VirtualBox logs, but nothing seemed useful...happy to post those if you need them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, this was caused by Intel Power Gadget (https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-power-gadget.html) that I had installed recently. Uninstalling it and restarting cleared up the problem.